# Is the EOS memo field data stored forever on the EOS blockchain?

Tags: memo

Is the eos memo field data that is attached to each transaction immutable and stored forever on the EOS blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the data is included in the transaction which affects its hash.  If the data were to be removed, the hash of the transaction would change, disrupting the nature of the block chain.

Comment: wouldn't that cause blockchain bloat?

Comment: The memo field has character limitations.

Comment: @Patoshi please accept this answer if it satisfies your question (it does)